# How to draw a squre around the scatter pots and remove only that pots in PrimeNg scatter type chart?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, charts

I have created a Scatter type chart to show some data, I want to draw a area and select the scatter pots whch is in that area and get that data,

I tried to find a way to do that. I could achive something like this approch. I can select any number of pots and remove only that post.

But I expect to select multiple pots using mouse (drawing a squre around the spots and remove that) and remove that How can I achive to that ?

if there is another chart component to do that plese let me know that too. I fond a one it calls fusionChart.There was a way to do that but problem is my angular 9 version project is not supporting to that.

Here is what I tried.....

### HTML

```
<p-chart
  #testChart
  type="scatter"
  [data]="data"
  [options]="options"
  width="400"
  height="400"
  (onDataSelect)="onDataSelect($event)"
></p-chart>

<button (click)="exclude()">Exclude</button>
```

### TS

```
excludeScatters = [];

  excludeScatters = [];

  data = {
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Scatter Dataset',
        data: [
          { x: 1, y: 0 },
          { x: 2, y: 10 },
          { x: 10, y: 5 },
          { x: 8, y: 0 },
          { x: 4, y: 10 },
          { x: 3, y: 5 },
          { x: 6, y: 4 },
          { x: 2, y: 9 },
          { x: 7, y: 3 },
          { x: 0, y: 4 },
          { x: 0, y: 5 },
          { x: 2, y: 7 },
          // Add more data points as needed
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.6)',
        borderColor: 'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
        pointRadius: 5,
        pointHoverRadius: 8,
      },
    ],
  };


 //Get the selected pots and store in a array;

  onDataSelect(event: any) {
    const selectedDatasetIndex = event.element._datasetIndex;
    const selectedDataIndex = event.element._index;
    const selectedValue =
      this.data.datasets[selectedDatasetIndex].data[selectedDataIndex];

    this.excludeScatters.push(selectedValue);
    console.log(this.excludeScatters);
  }

//When click the button find the index of the data in original arrat and remove those 

  exclude() {
    this.excludeScatters.forEach((i) => {
      
      let index = this.data.datasets[0].data.findIndex((el) => el === i);
      this.data.datasets[0].data.splice(index, 1);
    });
    this.testChart.refresh();
    this.excludeScatters = [];
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chart-sanbox-15y2qg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)